# Android Studio IDE can't recognize `commonMain` implemented dependencies - in shared module, KMM (Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile)

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

In a KMM project, I am using an Android Studio as the IDE for the project.

when I add a library in the common module as a dependency implementation in the `commonMain` source set, and use it in the shared module files.

the IDE can't find, import, analyze, or autocomplete with the library as it's now implemented at all, although when I build and run the project it runs successfully with no errors at all.

eg.

This is an implemented dependency written in `build.gradle.kts` of the shared module:

```kotlin
kotlin{
        sourceSets{
            val commonMain by getting {
                dependencies {
                    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime:0.4.0")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, when if try to `import kotlinx.datetime` in `Greating` class located in shared module created by the kmm plugin new project, the IDE complains with `Unresolved reference: datetime`.

But when I Build And Run the project it runs successfully.

("Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 1", tried on both win 10 and ubuntu 22.04 LTS, and still with same issue)

how can I fix it?

Comment: did you find any fix?